# Can there be some $x\in R$ such that $f(x)+2x=2(1+x^2)$ or $2f(x)+1=2x(1+x)$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=(1-x)^2(\sin x)^2+x^2$ for all $x\in R$.Then can there be some $x\in R$ such that $f(x)+2x=2(1+x^2)$ or $2f(x)+1=2x(1+x)$ ?

What would be the best approach for this problem?

Comment: Writing out the two equations in full after substituting f(x)...@charlestoncrabb....then i dont know how to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach is as you've started, with some algebra and observations about the sine function. For example, to investigate the first equality, we can substitute in $f$ and solve for the $\sin^2 x$ term:
$$\sin^2x=?\frac{(1-x)^2+1}{(1-x)^2},$$
(assuming of course $x\neq1$). You can take it from here?